# covert timestamps: are they immutable

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I have a series of the following type:

```
0     1978-01-18
1     1978-03-01
2     1978-03-22
3     1978-04-19
4     1978-05-17
         ...    
321   2017-06-14
322   2017-07-26
323   2017-09-20
324   2017-11-01
325   2017-12-13
```

The type of each element is a timestamp

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
```

When I try to convert the series to a normal date so that I can filter it directly
with inequalities signs, I just cannot. If I apply the pd.to_datetime() command, I still get a timestamp object. Somebody knows why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: can you test `pd.to_datetime(df[date_column],format='%Y-%m-%d')`?

Comment: I'm confused now what you're trying to do. Why don't datetime equalities work with a timestamp?

Comment: I tested what you suggest @Datanovice. Still get the same timestamp type as indicated in the question.

Comment: @roganjosh it just says I cannot compare timestamps with strings (e.g. I write serie[index]<'1994')

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. You don't want datetime objects at all, you want strings. Just use `.astype(str)` on the series. Or, convert the strings that you want to test _against_ into datetime objects

Comment: @roganjosh: why should the OP want to compare the str representation of what is obviously datetime? My suggestion would be: convert everything to_datetime ;-)

Comment: or better yet @roganjosh use `series.index.year < 1994` or `df[df[date].dt.year < 1994]` if your datetime is not the index.

Comment: last comment seems to work the best

Comment: @MrFuppes I agree; certainly is the better option but they can get away with strings due the ISO 8601 in this case :)